# MiniProfiler with EntityFramework 6 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have tried to wire-up a MiniProfiler to an existing project which used EF6 code first, aaaand it just makes me crazy now :)

The problem is that by default MiniProfiler works with EF 4.1, and for 6.0 they have implemented kind of quick solution https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/pull/134

But seems like it doesnt works for me.
Everytime I'm launching application I just getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledSqlClientDbProviderServices, MiniProfiler.EntityFramework6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

Did anybody faced similar issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The EF6 nuget has been published. It is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF6/) and can be installed using `Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF6 -Pre`

To initialize, simply call the following in your application startup logic:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Be sure to call this before using EF in any way.